# backspace after numbers in excel confusing formulas

Tags: excel, backspace

I want to remove a backspace (enter key) after some numbers. Trim doesn't recognise the backspace as a space. I have also tried find and replace but that doesn't recognise the backspace as a space either. I have also tried multiplying all the numbers by 1 in another column to get a purely numerical response but that doesn't work either. The cells are formatted as numbers.

Comment: By "Backspace" I assume you mean a carriage return. If yes, try a search for `ALT`-`010`

Comment: Try: `=--TRIM(CLEAN(A1))`

Comment: @ScottCraner Why the`--` ? I guess it makes a difference, but I would like to know why. Thanks :)

Comment: It changes the text value to numeric.  `-1*-1*TRIM(CLEAN(A1))` @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could Control-H to open up the find and replace. Then, in the "Find What" field, enter a Control-J. It'll look like a dot, but it's a line return.

If you just want it gone, leave "Replace With" blank and hit Replace All.